# WAMP Server takes another DocumentRoot than I prescribed

Tags: apache, wampserver

I have WAMP Server installed, which works fine—normally.

I have changed some settings in **httpd.conf**, including the `DocumentRoot` directive. But when I start the server, and open **localhost** through a web browser, it gives a `403 Forbidden` error. When I open the error log, I see the cause:

> *Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache2/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist*

But wait... In the **httpd.conf** file, the `DocumentRoot` directive is properly set to **A:/website/www/**.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your editing the wrong DocumentRoot.

I use another WAMP (Wamp-Developer) but I'm guessing that your httpd.conf's DocumentRoot is the server's (non-VirtualHost) DocumentRoot.

You're looking to edit the website's (localhost's) VirtualHost block, which is either at the end of httpd.conf or in another file (that's included by httpd.conf).

Run Apache via the command line like this:

```
httpd -S
```

It will show you where the VirtualHost is.

You'll also need to make sure that your custom DocumentRoot has all the permissions set for access.

```
<Directory /xxxx>
order allow,deny
allow from all
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you've uncommented this line in `httpd.conf`:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

`httpd-vhosts.conf` is the file where you can put your VirtualHost directives for having them separate from the rest, but it contains a sample VirtualHost (exactly your `dummy-host.example`) that is causing the error.

So you have to replace the sample host with your one(s).
But you can also comment the include line and write the VirtualHost directly in your httpd.conf.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to read the error log properly:

> Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache2/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist

So we have to find a directive in some file that is trying to define a virtual host. In my case (W7pro, WAMP) I found it in the following location:

> C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

Just edit the file and delete the corresponding virtual host directives.

Answer (score 0):

try 127.0.0.1, if it works. go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc and add (or uncomment) the following line:

> 127.0.0.1       localhost

Answer (score 0):

For me it was MSSQL reporting service:

> SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)

disabled it and it works.